# Bash equivalent .bash_logout for FISH shell

Tags: bash, config, fish

Generally I write my exit scripts for `bash` shell in `.bash_logout`. I recently started using `fish` shell. The `.bashrc` equivalent of `fish` is located in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` but where do I find the equivalent for `.bash_logout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of sourcing a specific file, you define an event handler that runs when the shell exists.

From http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#initialization:

> If you want to run a set of commands when fish exits, use an event handler that is triggered by the exit of the shell:
>
> ```
> function on_exit --on-process %self
>     echo fish is now exiting
> end
> ```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? What would it mean to exit upon exiting?

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Basically I enter into the `fish` shell from my `bash` shell. When u exit from the `fish` shell, it brings you back to the `bash` . I wanted to exit the shell prompt directly when I hit exit in `fish` shell.  So I added an `exit` command within the `on_exit` function so on exit it will invoke the `exit` command and in turn I'll exit the shell. But it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: You can configure your terminal emulator to run `fish` directly instead of `bash`.

Comment: I'm doing this on a remote server via ssh. I added the `fish` path to `.profile` so that `fish shell` gets loaded as soon as I login and it works. Is there any way to exit the shell when I exit from the `fish shell`?

Comment: Just run `ssh user@remotehost fish` instead of modifying your `.profile`; that runs `fish` as the remotes command, and terminates the connection as soon as the `fish` instance exits.

Comment: I tried it with 4 different commands: `ls`, `pwd`, `mkdir` & `fish`. All the 3 worked except `ssh user@remotehost fish`.

Comment: When you specify a command for ssh to run you normally do not get an interactive session -- specifically, no tty is allocated. You can force it with the `-t` flag: `ssh -t user@remotehost fish`. Alternatively, just ssh as normal and then do `exec fish` to replace the login shell with a fish shell.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow @chepner 's answer.
But, you can also override `exit` and `logout` function instead of a event listener!

```
function exit
    echo exiting...
    kill %self
end
```

> Do the same to `logout`

And, it works